# select data from Dataset Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, dataset

ok first ill explain what ive done.

First I imported an access db into my vb app it then named the dataset etc.

this is how my dataSet looks:
1 table
   4 columns

so Far i have this:

```
Dim ds As ElementsDataSet
    Dim dt As ElementsDataSet.ElementsDataTable
    Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Elements.accdb")
    Dim selectString As String = "Select Atomic Mass FROM Elements WHERE No =" & mol
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(selectString, conn)
If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()

Dim datareader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While datareader.Read = True

    MessageBox.Show(datareader.Item("Atomic Mass"))

End While

datareader.Close()
```

and upon executing this I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using a `SQLConnection` to open a Access database. This wont work.

You either need a SQLServer database or to use the `OleDbConnection` for a Access database.

Here is a Microsoft KB article to help you connect to the Access database: 
[How To Retrieve and Display Records from an Access Database by Using ASP.NET, ADO.NET, and Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308278) and this one over at CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8477/Using-ADO-NET-for-beginners

```
Private Sub ReadRecords()
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = Nothing
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = Nothing
    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Temp\Elements.accdb"))
        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Atomic Mass FROM Elements WHERE No =" & mol, conn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()    
        While reader.Read = True
        MessageBox.Show(reader.Item("Atomic Mass"))
        End While
    Finally

        If reader <> Nothing Then
            reader.Close()
        End If
        If conn <> Nothing Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks you this fixed my issue although instead of using Jet as the provider im using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0